# Nodejs port 8000 ,4000 not working on server

Tags: node.js

I am using nodejs for rest-api and my app running on 2000,3000 but when i use port 8000 it work on browser but it not working on iphone also i was opened port 8000 from whm.

Comment: Is it runing on `0.0.0.0` ip address?

Answer (score 1):

Try to run your application on `0.0.0.0` ip address, this guarantees it would be listening on all the configured network interfaces

```
var server = app.listen(8000, '0.0.0.0', function () {
    var host = server.address().address;
    var port = server.address().port;

    console.log('App listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

Comment: Did you test your server ip address with the 8000 port in your phone? Perhaps something like this: `192.168.24.34:8000` in other pc's browser connected to the same network

Comment: yes i have checked but it not working. Is this node.js issue or my server configuration problem ?

Comment: Are you sure your server is listening to 8000 port? if you are using linux try this: `netstat -ntlp | grep LISTEN` after you ran your application, look which ip and port is being used by your node process. Also check the message printed by your application after run.

Comment: And show us some code, so we can guess what's going on